# Dynamic Casting in Java with Variable Class Name

Tags: java

If I have a variable method param which takes a Class to cast to, how do I dynamically implement the cast? And how would I declare the variable `result`?

Obviously this is wrong,

```
public void test(Class destinationClass)
{
   (destinationClass)result = (destinationClass)getObject();
}
```

Note: getObject() returns an object castable to Destination Class. A Destination Class object is a child of getObject().

Comment: what does the method getObject return ?

Comment: What do you expect this dynamic cast to do? You can only call method which are known at compile time.  You can check `destinationClass.isInstance(getObject())`

Comment: getObject() returns an object castable to Destination Class. Destination Class is a child of the generic object returned by getObject().

Comment: It's not useful to try to do something like this. Since the target class is not known at compile time, the compiler can't check the types. Casting is only useful for static type checking, not for dynamic type checking. What problem exactly are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: I'm writing an abstract method that generalizes some behavior previously available with hard-coded class casts, such as KnownObject result = (KnownObject)getObject(). Now I'm trying to get away from specifics and allow you to specify which class to cast to at the last moment.

Comment: This looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you describe why you think you need such code? Could you post some specific code example of how you would like to use this method? For now I suspect you may be looking for generics, but I can't be sure with current state of your question.

Comment: I agree with Peter and others.  Casting (other than on some primitive types) doesn't actually change anything.  It changes how the compiler views an object's type, but it doesn't change anything at runtime.  If `x` was constructed with a certain class *C*, then after you cast it, it will still have the class *C*, and nothing about the object will change.  If you use a cast construct `(MyClass)x`, you're telling the compiler that you can use `MyClass` methods on the resulting object.  But casting to a type that the compiler doesn't know about doesn't even give you that.

Answer (score 4):

```
public <T> void test(Class<T> destinationClass) {
  T result = destinationClass.cast(getObject());
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection, if you want to create an object dynamically (this is useful when the exact types are not known at compile time)

```
public <T> T getObj(Class<T> target){
T obj= target.getConstructor().newInstance();
return obj;
}
```

This assumes that the target class has a no-args constructor, but you see the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case for generic methods.

```
class MyObject {
    private Object obj;

    public void setObject(Object o) {
        this.obj = o;
    }

    public <T>T getObject() { //notice return type
        return (T) obj;       //and cast
    }
}
```

Then just use this code to run it and see what it does.

```
MyObject o = new MyObject();

o.setObject("Hello World!");
String s = o.getObject();
System.out.println(s);

o.setObject(1000);
Integer i = o.getObject();
System.out.println(i);

s = o.getObject(); //will throw exception because the object is an integer

//can also use this to specify return type
o.<Integer>getObject();
```